# PHP works only after second click

Tags: php, mysql

I have code this php code:

```
$friendbutton;  
$sqla = "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user1='$usernotif' AND user2='$username' AND accepted='0'";
$query = mysqli_query($link,$sqla) or die(mysqli_error($link)); 
$row_counter = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($row_counter > 0) {
    $friendbutton ='<input id="Friend" type="submit" name="Delete" value="Unsend friend request"><br />';
    $type="Unsend";
    $_SESSION['type']=$type;
} else {
    $friendbutton='<input id="Friend" name="Send" type="submit" value="Send friend request"><br />';
}
```

And this in my `friend.php`:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['Send'])){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO friends(user1, user2, datemade) VALUES('$usernotif','$username',now())";
    $sqla = "INSERT INTO notifications(username,initiator,date_time,type) VALUES('$username','$usernotif',now(),'Friend')";
}
```

But both Send and Delete work after second click.

Comment: post your html as well. opps my mistake. its in ur php code. nvm

Comment: @Bsienn Not much of html there is just form and i echo $friendbutton there

Comment: is there any error in console on first click

Comment: @Farhan Nope.It actually deletes that data from database but it does not change $friendbutton it stays the same.It changes only after 2 click

Comment: There is no session declared on first load. If you send the data and refresh the page. It should work with one click. try that.
Also this is not a constructive way of doing things. You should take lesson on form & submission.

Comment: @Bsienn Yes it does work.After refreshing.But it is same as clicking twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
<?php
$sqla = "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user1='$usernotif' AND  user2='$username'
AND accepted='0'";

$query = mysqli_query($link, $sqla) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$row_counter = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if ( !empty($row_counter) ){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO friends(user1, user2, datemade) VALUES('$usernotif','$username',now())";
    $sqla = "INSERT INTO notifications(username,initiator,date_time,type) VALUES('$username','$usernotif',now(),'Friend')";
}
elseif (isset($_FORM['delete'])){
    //delete query goes here
}

?>

<form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<?php
    if ( !empty($row_counter) )
        echo '<input type="submit" name="Delete" value="Unsend friend request"><br />';
    else
        echo '<input type="submit" name="Send" value="Send friend request"><br />';
?>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to use ```!empty($row_counter)``` instead isset

Comment: @arma Yes thank you!But it only send i added DELETE SQL but it is not deleting it only send

Comment: @MuradMurader arma is right, u need to use `!empty($row_counter)`. i gave u a sample to carry on. Its a basic structure and you need to learn how things work. my given example should work. i'm not sure whar ur current code looks like and where is the problem.

Comment: Yes thanks i changed things a little bit but your code is right).